# Почему приложение не видит модули php?

Tags: php, windows, nextcloud

Я клонировал репозиторий некст клауда и установил php 8.1. Но когда я запускаю сервер с помощью команды `php -S localhost:8080` и открываю ссылку, то вылезает ошбка, в которой говорится, что не установлены модули mbstring, GD, cURL и OpenSSL. Но они установлены и лежат в папке с php в ext.

Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

**UPD1:**

Написал `php --info`. В поле `Loaded Configuration File` стоит `(none)`. И в `php -m` нет нужных модулей.

Попробовал написать `php -c путь\к\phpini\проекта\php.ini`, но выходит ошибка:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'modules/awscrt.so' (tried: modules/awscrt.so (╨Э╨╡ ╨╜╨░╨╣╨┤╨╡╨╜ ╤Г╨║╨░╨╖╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨╝╨╛╨┤╤Г╨╗╤М), C:\php\ext\php_modules/awscrt.so.dll (╨Э╨╡ ╨╜╨░╨╣╨┤╨╡╨╜ ╤Г╨║╨░╨╖╨░╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨╝╨╛╨┤╤Г╨╗╤М)) in Unknown on line 0
```

В php.ini только одна строка `extension=modules/awscrt.so`.

**UPD2:**

Попробовал убрать `extension=modules/awscrt.so` из php.ini. Добавил модули в папку ext проекта и в php.ini их указал:

```
extension=C:\путь\к\проекту\ext\php_mbstring.dll
extension=C:\путь\к\проекту\ext\php_gd.dll
extension=C:\путь\к\проекту\ext\php_openssl.dll
extension=C:\путь\к\проекту\ext\php_curl.dll
extension=C:\путь\к\проекту\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

И написал в консоли `php -c "C:\путь\к\проекту\3rdparty\aws\aws-crt-php\php.ini" "C:\путь\к\проекту\index.php"`.

Вернулась какая-то html страница:

[image]

Но если запустить сервер и открыть некст клауд, вылезет та же ошибка, что нет модулей.

Comment: а они включены в php.ini ?

Comment: @splash58 нет, там только строка `extension=modules/awscrt.so`. В php.ini нужно просто написать названия модулей?

Comment: что-то такое `extension=php_curl.dll` надо раскомментировать или написать для каждого модуля

Comment: @splash58 в php.ini в папке проекта попробовал это сделать, но не сработало. Еще в папке с самим php в Program files в php.ini-development нашел эти модули. Тут они уже были, но закомментированы. Раскомментировал, но тоже не помогло

Comment: а что у вас в настройках написано - откуда читать php.ini ? По идее, должен быть просто php.ini в папке php

Comment: ну и сервер не забывайте перезапустить после изменений

Comment: @splash58 сейчас написал `php --info` и в поле `Loaded Configuration File => (none)` так и должно быть?

Comment: не помню - сейчас php под рукой нет, но, думаю, что нет